# Angular 4 app build errors after `yarn install`

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, yarnpkg

I have an app created with Angular CLI and I've decided to move from npm to yarn. But I'm not able to build project with `ng build` or even start it using `ng serve` after installing dependencies with yarn.

This is what `ng --version` command returns:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
node: 6.11.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.3
@angular/common: 4.4.3
@angular/compiler: 4.4.3
@angular/core: 4.4.3
@angular/forms: 4.4.3
@angular/http: 4.4.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.3
@angular/router: 4.4.3
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.3
```

After removing node modules and installing them again with `npm install` everything works as expected and after `npm list --local --depth=0` I can see:

```
+-- @angular/animations@4.4.3
+-- @angular/cli@1.0.3
+-- @angular/common@4.4.3
+-- @angular/compiler@4.4.3

...

+-- moment@2.18.1
+-- ngx-bootstrap@1.9.3
+-- protractor@5.1.2
+-- rxjs@5.4.3
+-- ts-node@2.0.0
+-- tslint@5.7.0
+-- typescript@2.5.2
`-- zone.js@0.8.17
```

After `yarn install` `npm list --local --depth=0` returns:

```
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/animations@4.4.3
| `-- tslib@1.7.1
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.4.3
| `-- tslib@1.7.1
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.4.3

...

| `-- moment@2.18.1
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY fullcalendar-scheduler@1.7.1
| +-- fullcalendar@3.5.1
| +-- jquery@3.2.1
| `-- moment@2.18.1
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY lodash@4.17.4
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY moment@2.18.1
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY ngx-bootstrap@1.9.3
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.4.3
| `-- symbol-observable@1.0.4
`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.8.17
```

Above command returns also information about missing packages:

```
npm ERR! missing: @angular/animations@4.4.3, required by atomiumplus-angular@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: @angular/common@4.4.3, required by atomiumplus-angular@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: @angular/compiler@4.4.3, required by atomiumplus-angular@0.0.0

...

npm ERR! missing: tslib@1.7.1, required by @angular/forms@4.4.3
npm ERR! missing: tslib@1.7.1, required by @angular/http@4.4.3
npm ERR! missing: tslib@1.7.1, required by @angular/platform-browser@4.4.3
npm ERR! missing: tslib@1.7.1, required by @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.3
npm ERR! missing: tslib@1.7.1, required by @angular/router@4.4.3
npm ERR! missing: moment@2.18.1, required by @types/moment@2.13.0
npm ERR! missing: jquery@3.2.1, required by floating-scroll@2.3.1
npm ERR! missing: jquery@3.2.1, required by fullcalendar@3.5.1
npm ERR! missing: moment@2.18.1, required by fullcalendar@3.5.1
npm ERR! missing: fullcalendar@3.5.1, required by fullcalendar-scheduler@1.7.1
npm ERR! missing: jquery@3.2.1, required by fullcalendar-scheduler@1.7.1
npm ERR! missing: moment@2.18.1, required by fullcalendar-scheduler@1.7.1
npm ERR! missing: symbol-observable@1.0.4, required by rxjs@5.4.3
```

I would like to add that I've tried newest version of yarn (1.1.0) and older version (1.0.1) also.

What should I do to install dependencies with yarn properly?

Comment: Have you set `yarn` as @angular/cli package manager?

Comment: Yes, I've set it using `ng set packageManager=yarn` command for local and global Angular CLI also.

Comment: What `yarn list` command returns after you do `yarn install`?

Comment: what exactly error are you getting when `yarn install` ?

Comment: More info from you would be helpful. Looks like something should be corrupted on yarn side when you switched the install between the two. Try `yarn check` or `yarn install --check-files` and see what is happening. If that is not solving the problem try also `yarn install --force`, this should empty all cache and reinstall forcing all the dependencies.